# How to uninstall redundant python instance?

Tags: python, uninstall, software-uninstall

When I execute:

```
$ which -a python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

This bothers me because execute `python` directly will execute `/usr/local/bin/python`, but it can't link to correct dependencies. So, how could i correctly uninstall it? I've checked all packages.

I've checked `dpkg --search /usr/local/bin/python` but only get `no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/python`. Seems it was installed by compiling sources of python and `make install`. But now how can i remove it?

Comment: Packages do not install to `/usr/local/`. That looks like software manually compiled and installed.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above, and how can I uninstall it?

Comment: Unless you used `checkinstall`, or have the original makefile around, there's no clean way.

Comment: @muru Sorry, I'm not quite sure if i installed it manually, and i just took "Python" as the keyword during searching, so i didn't see that post.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to uninstall it clearly.
Just found the .tar file again and `make install` it again, it will output what it is installing. And just delete all the files and folder shows in there.

Comment: If you had the original makefile, you could try `make uninstall` as well.

Comment: yeah but it doesnt work . i think its quite normal for makefile not having uninstall target

Comment: true, but I'd expect software as popular as python to support it.