# Remove separate version of Python 2.7 after install

Tags: python, software-uninstall

I was trying to install a separate version of python 2.7 (2,7.10) on my Ubuntu machine. The idea was to run them separately, but when I installed it from source, it became the default version. I assume because they are both releases of 2.7.

Now I have some issues with my python (see example below) - is there a way to safely remove this new version of python to revert back to the system install of 2.73?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uninstall redundant python instance?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/575339/how-to-uninstall-redundant-python-instance)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I fixed this by running:

```
which -a python
```

This gave me 2 different python binaries:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

where `/usr/bin/python` was the original.

Both of these paths were symlinks to `python2.7` in the same directories, that is `/usr/bin/python` was a symlink to `/usr/bin/python2.7` and so on.

I simply symlinked the `/usr/local/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.7` and the conflicts were resolved.

I am not sure if this is the best solution but it seems to work.